# IE 10, 11 iframe and fontface in external css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I'm loading external css with link in iframe.

css contains @font-faces

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('/assets/fonts/myFont.woff');
}
```

and fonts are applied in all browsers except IE 10, 11 (I'm not intrested in below).
The css itself is loaded (other rules are applied in IE too) but @font-faces not.

If I emped font face with hardcore style tag, it works.

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('/assets/fonts/myFont.woff');
}
</style>
```

Maybe some one found a way to fix this for external css resource?

Comment: Can we see the path to the font? that could be wrong.

Comment: I've added. As I've said if to put styles inside the page code, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I believe its a bug in IE and the only workaround is to hardwire css in  tag id iframe document's head.

Comment: I think this happens only when the iframe's content is on `https` and the main page is not.

Answer (score 3):

You must add your type font with `EOT` extension font, because IE support Embedded OpenType (EOT) file (.eot or .ote format).

If you do not have `.eot` or `.ote` file, convert font in this url [everythingfont](http://everythingfonts.com/).

Correct font format,

```
 <style type="text/css" >
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'Sri-TSCRegular';
    src: url('sri-tsc-webfont.eot');
    src: url('sri-tsc-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sri-tsc-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sri-tsc-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('sri-tsc-webfont.svg#Sri-TSCRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
   }
   body { font-family: "Sri-TSCRegular", serif }
  </style>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: IE 9,10,11 supports woff. The problems is not in format. If you read carefully I've said that it all works if to put font-face in <style> tag. It does not with external css file.

Comment: font-family declare on external css file?

Comment: you also extend css style library into iframe

Comment: I place link tag into iframe document head. It loads css (other rules applied, but not font-face)

Answer (score 1):

We had the almost the exact same problem. We were using Google's Webfont loader to load css fonts in both the parent and in the iFrame.

The iFrame was cross-domain so we couldn't use the iFrame method built-in to the Webfont api. The iFrame was responsible for loading it's own fonts.

The Webfont loader also provides callbacks for when a font is successfully loaded or not. What we found using IE (specifically version 11) loading the Debugging Tool AFTER the page load, was that the font loader was placing an inactive class on the HTML tag, which means the font did not successfully. If we ran the debugger before the page load, the fonts would magically load as expected and the web font loader would put the Active class on the HTML element, indicating a successful load.

What was stranger still, is when we tried to write the error to the console when a font failed, nothing would happen - never figured out what the issue was with that.

After doing plenty of research, we were able to replicate good behavior if we hard-coded the @FontFace declarations in our page's, head, just as the author of this question did. But since our service has no idea what fonts our users will be using, there is no way hard-coding styles was an option.

In the end, it seems to be some kind of caching bug, since the font loader worked while the debugger was running (apparently IE uses different caching rules while debugging - good idea, NOT). We tried setting No Cache metatags to no avail.

Anyway, the only viable answer I found was here:
[IE8 web font iframe bug workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768029/ie8-web-font-iframe-bug-workarounds)
Specifically unloading and reloading your stylesheets:

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
for(var s = 0, slen = sheets.length; s < slen; s++) {
  sheets[s].disabled = true;
  sheets[s].disabled = false;
}
```

I hope this helps some other poor coder who has yet again been suckered by the incompetent team over at IE.

Comment: Thanks, maybe we will try, currently we are embedding css fonts data inside the page.